# four decimal zeros and no decimal point php

Tags: php, mysql, string, formatting

the code below is supposed to format the number i am getting after running multiplication in mysql to get data in a temporary table. problem is the result of the multiplication is not following the formatting. I want the number formatted to have four decimal places and the zeros retained.

```
<?php
$tv = $row_cscs_report['TOTAL_VALUE'];
$vr = str_replace('.', '', $tv);
echo $vr;
?>
```

Comment: You can use sprintf with the %f formatting to make this happen. `$vr = sprintf('%.04f', $tv);`

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful...

Comment: @ryantxr If you're going to answer the question, post it as an answer.

Comment: A one line answer? Seems like overkill.

Comment: @Nick am afraid this is all I got by way of sample data. The code above works but because the data is coming from a temporary table the conversion does not work.

Comment: All you've given us is code... what we need is the values that the code is for i.e. what values could be in `$row_cscs_report['TOTAL_VALUE']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), specifying 4 decimal places and telling it that the decimal and thousands separators should both be empty:

```
$tv = 3547.66;
echo number_format($tv, 4, '', '');
```

Output:

```
35476600
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this:

```
<?php
$tv = $row_cscs_report['TOTAL_VALUE'];
$vr = sprintf("%.4f", $tv);
echo $vr;
?>
```

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/pl/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Thanks @Eboo but this code still shows the decimal point. The aim is to remove the decimal point and still keep the four zeros visible.